# How to print input value from a dynamic table created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

Let me ask some questions about a dynamic table created with JavaScript.

Here are my codes.

```js
var num;
var tag = "<table id='dytable'>";
var data = document.getElementById("table1");

function makingtable(a1) {
  var b1 = parseInt(a1);
  num = b1;
  for (var j = 1; j <= b1; j++) {
    tag += "<tr>"
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
      tag += "<td class = 'autoInc'>";
      tag += "<input type = 'text' id='one'>";
      tag += "</td>";
      tag += "<td class = 'autoInc'>";
      tag += "<input type = 'text' id='two'>";
      tag += "</td>";
    }
    tag += "</tr>";
  }
  tag += "</table>";
  area.innerHTML = tag;
}

function printingTable() {
  var tag1 = "<table>";

  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    tag1 += "<tr>";
    for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
      tag1 += "<td>";
      // ???
      tag1 += "</td>";
    }
    tag1 += "</tr>";
  }

  tag1 += "</table>";
  area1.innerHTML = tag1;
}
```

```html
the number of words: <input type="number" id="txt1">
<button onclick="makingtable(txt1.value)">enter</button>
<div id="area"></div>
<hr/>
<button onclick="printingTable()">print</button>
<div id="area1"></div>
```

1. I'd like to input the values in all the columns of the dynamic table, and then make a table of the same size as the one I made before and print it out.
2. Is there a way to add a code to the part marked with three question marks in the function named **printingTable()**?
3. In fact, my ultimate goal is to store all the values input in the dynamic table and output them randomly. Is there a good way to achieve my goal?

- I've been searching how to print using an array within JavaScript for a long time, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: IDs have to be unique. You can't use the same `id="one"` and `id="two"` on each row of the input table.

Comment: `for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++)` isn't much of a loop, since it'll run once and exit....

Comment: You can use `area.rows[i-1].cells[j].querySelector("input").value` to get the value of the input in the corresponding cell of the input table.